# Bootstrap Navbar with link dont work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

Look, i have one big problem here, in my navbar, i needed create one single button in the right, and only this button need to bring another page, "portal.html" another buttons just slide index, like index.html#photos and etc.

Another buttons works fine:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">InC - Inglês corporativo</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#main-slider"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#empresa">Empresa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#pricing">Serviços</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Perguntas Frequentes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="portal.html"><b>Portal Acadêmico</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i found the problem, but i dont know how to solve.
in Main.css look what i found:

```
$('.navbar-nav > li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).find('>a').prop('hash');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

So... anyone can help me? :)
Thanks anyway!

Comment: you found javascript code in a css file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set one unique id to that li

```
 <li id="btn"><a href="portal.html"><b>Portal Acadêmico</b></a></li>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $('.navbar-nav > li').click(function (event) {
            if ($(this)[0].id != 'btn') {
                var target = $(this).find('>a').prop('hash');
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                }, 500);
            }
        });
```